# How do I set up trackable links in Triggered Email to track ClickEvents?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, content-builder

I am having difficulty figuring out how to add a link to an email created in Content Builder and sent using a Triggered Send that will create a ClickEvent in Marketing Cloud when a link or button on an email is clicked.

I have no problem retrieving events (Bounces, Opens, Unsubs, etc.) using SOAP Apis, but I cannot seem to figure out to configure the tracking of clicks in a sent email so that a ClickEvent is created.  I have no retrievable ClickEvents using SOAP calls and also see no clicks tracked in the Tracking Reports within Marketing Cloud itself.

I seem to be missing any documentation, as well.

Comment: are your links dynamic or formed/filled via AMPScript or SSJS?

Comment: At the moment they are simple html anchor links.  I just trying to see a ClickEvent so I can log some tracking in my application.  Do the links need to contain AMPScript or SSJS to be tracked?

Comment: No, utilizing AMPScript can be a cause for links not to track. Have you verified that you have the 'track clicks' option checked in your Triggered Email configuration? Without this checked, SFMC will not wrap your links in the necessary redirects to track clicks

Comment: Oh good grief, thats it.  Clearly right there in front of me.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For easy reference should anyone else come into this issue, see below that solved OP's issue via Comments:**

Have you verified that you have the 'track clicks' option checked in your Triggered Email configuration? Without this checked, SFMC will not wrap your links in the necessary redirects to track clicks

[image]

Comment: Also note that in order to enable Click Tracking when creating or updating a TriggeredSendDefinition object via Soap Api, you must set IsWrapped and IsWrappedSpecified to true in your request.